# How to compare MySql data exist in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to compare Mysql data exist in php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btnReg'])) {
    $user2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_user']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `Username` = '" . $user2 . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result = DataProvider::execNonQueryAffectedRows($query);
    if ($result == 1) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Username already exists</strong></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Sign Up Success .</strong></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm try , but when i use other username it show Username Already Exist . Check in code $result . Pls help me , Thanks you

Comment: what's your target dude?

Comment: Register  new accounts , but i check account does not exists it show error ( Username Already Exist ) you can check in my Website . http://sampsv.net/dangnhap.php

Comment: `SELECT` query doesn't `affect` rows. Check for returned-set rows count instead, or modify query to `SELECT count(id) as count FROM "accounts" WHERE "Username" = '".$user2."' LIMIT 1` and check for something like `$row = DataProvider::execQueryGetFirstRow($query); if (intval(@$row['count'])) { ... }`

Comment: please check your query result once. what results you get from query?

Comment: The only way this feature can work is that you add `UNIQUE` constraint to your `Username` column. **You don't** check if user exists. You just insert. If the `Username` exists, database will tell you and PHP will interpret that as an `Exception`. You can't check for username first by querying. You will receive false results and you will end up with duplicated data.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "your_username";
    $password = "your_password";
    $dbname = "your_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    if (isset($_POST['btnReg'])) {

      $user2=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["reg_user"]);
     // mysqli_real_escape_string is used instead of mysql_real_escape_string

         $sql =  "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username = '$user2' LIMIT 1";
         $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Username already exists</strong></div>';
           } 
           else {
           echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Sign Up Success .</strong></div>';
           }
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: What is the problem?? Why -1?

Comment: i don't know , someone rate your answser

Comment: Your problem is solved or not by this code?

Comment: not solved !! i'm stuck here

Comment: if username is not exist then print some string in else condition. check it comes there or not.

Comment: thanks you , i'm solved this :)

Comment: I 'm glad your issue is resolved. :)

Comment: `$user2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_user']);` how can this possibly work with `mysqli_`? those different MySQL APIs do NOT intermix.

Comment: you're not listening to me ^^^ *why?* @RaviHirani and why haven't you edited in order to use the correct escaping function? it's misleading for future visitors to the question/answer and this says that mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` is OK, which it is not.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks Brothers for pointing out my mistakes. I will take care of it next time.

Comment: @RaviHirani thanks for fixing that Ravi :) and you're welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :- I have changed syntax and make it right as you expected.

Comment: Please take care of the "try this" this time. Do not wait.

Comment: @JayBlanchard:- I will add description as you said and thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$result = DataProvider::execNonQueryAffectedRows($query);
```

to this

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($result));
```

then use this to replace your previous if statement

```
if($num_rows == 1){
// your stuff
}else{
// your stuff
}
```

Comment: it not working ! still (Username Already Exists)

Comment: it means the username you passed to the database already exist, your if statement is all correct. Are you sure the username you passed to the DB is not exist?

Comment: Yes ! i'm sure @@! My database only 3 records

Comment: it's a bit odd. hmmph, try change your $user2 value to something else , for example "testvalue". If the return message is "Sign up success..", then I believe your username you passed to the database already exists in the database.

Comment: This is a bad solution prone to concurrency issues.

Comment: Still not working :( thank you